# disable validate['required'] from select field in Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have been using jquery validate plugin on my page. So here is my scenario:

I have two buttons Button1 and Button2, when I click on Button1, validation for select field/ dropdown should be enabled and when I click on Button2, validation should be disabled.

Tried following approaches without any success :

```
$("#"+elementId).attr("validation", "");

$("#"+elementId).removeAttr("validation");

$("#"+elementId).removeClass("required");

$("#"+elementId).removeClass("validation");
```

need to remove validation for the below HTML

`<div class='question ' id='questionDiv_16881'><div class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-corner-all ui-li-has-count ui-btn-up-c"><div class="questionText">2.11 Multi-Part - Conditional - Drop Down</div></div><div class="mainQuestion"><div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <legend>Multi-Part - Conditional - Drop Down</legend>
                <input type="radio" class="required checklistQuestionField" name="Question_16881" id="Question_16881_DropDown" value="Drop Down"/>
                <label for="Question_16881_DropDown">Drop Down</label><input type="radio" class="required checklistQuestionField" name="Question_16881" id="Question_16881_NoDropDown" value="No Drop Down"/>
                <label for="Question_16881_NoDropDown">No Drop Down</label>
                <img class="questionImage" src="" data-role="questionReferenceImage" id="Question_16881_ReferenceImage"/>
            </fieldset></div></div><div class='questionParts' id='questionPartsDiv_16881'></div></div>`

Select field appears when user clicks on "DropDown" button

`<label for="QuestionPart_717496" generated="true" class="" style="display: block;">This field is required.</label><legend>Drop Down<span style="vertical-align: top;color:red;margin-left:5px;"></span></legend><div class="ui-select"><div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"><span class="checklistQuestionField">Select...</span></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span><select id="QuestionPart_717496" class="checklistQuestionField dropdownValid" validation="required" name="QuestionPart_717496">
                     <option>Select...</option>
                     <option value="List Item 1">List Item 1</option><option value="List Item 2">List Item 2</option><option value="List Item 3">List Item 3</option><option value="List Item 4">List Item 4</option><option value="List Item 5">List Item 5</option>
                 </select></div></div>`

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code ASAP please? What do you mean by *validation enabled/disabled*?

Comment: removing the class as required

Comment: Are you setting classes on the html objects that help perform validation or are you talking about the html required and novalidate attributes?

Comment: please find the HTML in the question above